# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException - The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, dll, xamlparseexception

First of all, using Windows 7, x86 build on a 64 bit machine, VS2010.

While running our CS gui code, we are getting the problem seen below:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

I have done a lot of searching and have been unable to find anyone with this "Additional Information" problem.  And this is all the information I have:

- The project never seems to actually reach any of our code.  Breakpoints are never hit.
- The call stack (which I'll paste below) seems to confirm this.  It's almost like the thing is breaking on start up.
- The problem is not in our code.  One member of our team has the GUI working - and we don't know what is configured differently on her computer.

We are all really stumped.  I want to give you guys whatever information I can to help us - but I'm stuck to the point where I don't even know what would help you help me.  If anyone knows how to diagnose this problem - or can explain this behavior and has a solution, we would love to know.

Call stack pasted below:

```
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri) + 0x170 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) + 0x40 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream) + 0x20b bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext pc) + 0xad bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri resourceLocator, bool bSkipJournaledProperties) + 0xed bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.DoStartup() + 0xa8 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application..ctor.AnonymousMethod__1(object unused) + 0x39 bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x52 bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x3a bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() + 0xac bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state) + 0x38 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x41 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() + 0x5b bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() + 0x16b bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x5a bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x9b bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) + 0x6b bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x52 bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x3a bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x10e bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) + 0xf1 bytes 
user32.dll!74e662fa()   
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]    
user32.dll!74e66d3a()   
user32.dll!74e66ce9()   
user32.dll!74e677c4()   
user32.dll!74e6788a()   
[Managed to Native Transition]  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0xb1 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x49 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() + 0x4b bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) + 0x17 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x6f bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x26 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1b bytes 
FBE_CSharpUI.exe!FBE_CSharpUI.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes   C#
mscoreei.dll!6154f4f3()     
KernelBase.dll!751c1e59()   
mscoree.dll!66ab7efd()  
mscoree.dll!66ab7f16()  
mscoree.dll!66ab4de3()  
kernel32.dll!7505338a()     
ntdll.dll!772b9f72()    
ntdll.dll!772b9f45()
```

Edit: This is the inner exception:

```
-       InnerException  {"The method or operation is not implemented."} System.Exception {System.NotImplementedException}
+       [System.NotImplementedException]    {"The method or operation is not implemented."} System.NotImplementedException
        _className  null    string
        _data   null    System.Collections.IDictionary
        _dynamicMethods null    object
        _exceptionMethod    null    System.Reflection.MethodBase
        _exceptionMethodString  null    string
        _helpURL    null    string
        _HResult    -2147467263 int
+       _innerException null    System.Exception
+       _ipForWatsonBuckets 1571861614  System.UIntPtr
        _message    "The method or operation is not implemented."   string
        _remoteStackIndex   0   int
        _remoteStackTraceString null    string
+       _safeSerializationManager   {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager} System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager
        _source null    string
+       _stackTrace {sbyte[192]}    object {sbyte[]}
        _stackTraceString   null    string
        _watsonBuckets  null    object
        _xcode  -532462766  int
+       _xptrs  0   System.IntPtr
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HelpLink    null    string
        HResult -2147467263 int
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
+       IPForWatsonBuckets  1571861614  System.UIntPtr
        IsTransient false   bool
        Message "The method or operation is not implemented."   string
        RemoteStackTrace    null    string
        Source  "PresentationFramework" string
        StackTrace  "   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType bamlType, Int16 typeId)\r\n   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16 typeId)\r\n   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart()\r\n   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()\r\n   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_BamlRecords()\r\n   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Read()\r\n   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)\r\n   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)"  string
+       TargetSite  {System.Xaml.XamlType ResolveBamlType(BamlType, Int16)} System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
        WatsonBuckets   null    object
+       Static members
```

Comment: It could possibly be something in the constructor of your XAML window/control. You say it's not in your code, but at this point I'm not sure how you could be sure of that. Is there anything in the inner exception of that exception?

Comment: I'm sure of that because my code is identical to my teammate's code, which works.

I just posted the inner exception.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21785206/593090)